# Enable Vim Syntax Highlighting By Default

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I know how to turn syntax highlighting on and off in vim by running this in the editor:

```
:syntax on/off
```

But I want syntax highlighting to be enabled by default, so I don't have to turn it on every time I run vim.

How do I do this?

Comment: Perhaps move to the Vim Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 221, accepted):

Edit your `$HOME/.vimrc` (Unix/Linux/OSX) or `$HOME/_vimrc` (Windows) to include the following line:

```
syntax on
```

**EDIT**

If your syntax highlighting doesn't work when you start Vim, you probably don't have a
`$HOME/.vimrc` or `$HOME/_vimrc` (known collectively as `vimrc` from now on). In that case, you have two options:

- Create an empty `vimrc`.
- Copy `vimrc_example.vim` as your `vimrc` (recommended, thanks @oyenamit). You can find `vimrc_example.vim` in the runtime directory.

The location of the runtime directory varies between operating systems:

- On my system (Arch Linux, and Mac, thanks @totophe), it's in `/usr/share/vim/vim73`.
- On Windows, it's in `\Program Files\Vim\vim73`.

Comment: I cant find .vimrc, im using a mac running Lion. I can find .viminfo

Comment: If there isn't one, you can create it. Just type :e ~/.vimrc to vim, type in the line and save (:w).

Comment: @lilroo While this solves your problem, I would advise you against creating a vimrc from scratch. Instead, pickup the example vimrc from the following location: /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/vimrc_example.vim. Copy this file to your $HOME as .vimrc. It switches on a lot of basic stuff for you automatically (syntax, search highlighting, backup etc). You can then tweak it based on your needs.

Comment: Is there any difference between `syntax on` and `syntax enable`?

Comment: @Sonique `syntax enable` keeps your color settings, `syntax on` overrides them (`:help :syn-on`).

Comment: The Mac folder is `/usr/share/vim/vim73/`. The one in the response supposes you have installed an extra application.

Comment: Make sure you add `syntax on` to `/etc/vim/vimrc` file (sudo required), to enable syntax on system-wide files (e.g. config files at /etc/)

Comment: Now even `~/.vimrc` is colored :)

Answer (score 11):

Also, to highlight the syntax of a **Specific File TYPE** (or programming language extension), you can use following commands, while file is already opened in Vim and you want to try syntax highlighting on the fly:

```
:set filetype=php
```

OR shortcut:

```
:se ft=php
```

Above commands will change the syntax-highlighting for currently opened file as it should be for PHP code.

Comment: The above method is especially helpful for when you have an unsaved file that you want to set the syntax highlighting for (e.g. when you use vim as a notepad with markdown)

Answer (score 7):

Uncommenting the "syntax on" in vimrc file.

Move to the directory,

```
cd /etc/vim/

vim vimrc
```

now search *"syntax"*  and uncomment it. Save it and reopen the file in vim.

Comment: Best way for me. Tks. If you don't have `syntax` just add, ```syntax enable```. Then ```source vimrc```. You got it permanently for later use

Answer (score 3):

For anyone that gets here because of TurnKeyLinux using `vim-tiny` which doesn't have the syntax module enabled try this article to install full `vim`

http://www.turnkeylinux.org/forum/support/20140108/solved-bash-command-not-found-after-replacing-package

**tl;dr**

```
# apt-get remove vim-tiny
# apt-get install vim
# hash vim
# vim
```

Comment: FWIW as of v14.0, you can just install vim and it all works as you'd expect (regardless of whether you uninstall vim-tiny or not). It was a bug in the way vim-tiny was configured to run as 'vim'. Now it updates the binary path properly...

Answer (score 2):

I also found that this is one of the lessons in `vimtutor`.

To find it, you can type command `vimtutor` in your Terminal (I used on Mac), and scroll down to see if there is a lesson called `CREATE A STARTUP SCRIPT` (for me it was Lesson 7.2), where it describes how to set up an initial `vimrc` file.

Comment: I have trouble with this. Running the tutorial has been fine although I don't have a $VIMRUNTIME set so I have no idea where this vimrc_example.vim is stored.

Answer (score 1):

In my `$HOME/.vimrc` I load a color scheme (solarized) and found that I need to place `syntax on` *after* I load the plugin. If it's before loading the plugin it doesn't work.

```
" this turns syntax highlighting on by default

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
Plugin 'lifepillar/vim-solarized8'

syntax on
```

```
" this does not turn syntax highlighting on by default

syntax on

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
Plugin 'lifepillar/vim-solarized8'
```

Answer (score 1):

To Find the vimrc_example.vim as suggested in answers above

```
Command : sudo find /usr -iname "vimrc_example.vim"
```