# Colorful Python Syntax in vim?

Tags: python, macos, ubuntu, vim

I was wondering how can I get this colorful `syntax highlighting` in `vim` on my Mac. I didn't add any libraries on my `ubuntu` desktop to get the syntax as shown in the image. Is it possible to get this behavior on `Mac` as well?

[image: python syntax on ubuntu]

Comment: What exactly do you mean? In your editor? What editor?

Comment: Sry. I want this behavior in vim

Comment: That can be done with `:syntax on` in `vim`. [Add it to your `.vimrc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272501/vim-default-syntax-highlighting) to make it persistent.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Mac OSX edit your .vimrc file:

```
vi ~/.vimrc
```

and add the following:

```
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
```

Save and close (`:x`) and try opening your python file again.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are referring to. If you are using a text editor in your terminal such as vim, then there is probably a plugin you can install to enable syntax highlighting. If you just want to style a Python file, then you might want to check out [pygments](http://pygments.org/)

See also:

- https://superuser.com/questions/125938/syntax-highlighting-in-terminal-for-python

Alternatively, you might want to try out [iPython](http://ipython.org/)