# vim - disable special marking of executables

Tags: vim

Is there any way to disable different marking of executable files? They are colored differently and marked with asterisk, both on vim's :Explore and NERDtree.

Comment: `:set filetype=` or `:syntax off` - see `:help filetype` and `:help syntax` and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272501/vim-default-syntax-highlighting).

Comment: I am talking about files in tree view, not the one being edited.

Comment: What? Disabling all syntax? I don't want that.

Comment: Then I guess you'll have to override the syntax highlighting rules for executable files in the `netrw` syntax (`/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/netrw.vim`). Btw, you do know that `:set filetype=` only applies to the current view, right? Any file you open will have syntax highlighting enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like only solution is to remove executable permission for those files.